# sqlite3.OperationalError y NameError: name 'e' is not defined al cargar datos

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3, python-3.9

Llevo usando SQL desde hace poco tiempo, de hecho aprendí a usarlo en un curso hace poco de forma programática para poder incorporar datos de una forma más rápida.
He intentado adaptar el código a mis necesidades actuales modificando unicamente los datos sobre las tablas que deseo incorporar a mi base de datos pero siempre obtengo el mismo error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alba/Fernando/SQL/Galvez_Sanchez_Fernando_Jose_SQL/Parseadores/DESEQ2_TE_only.py", line 47, in open_clinvar_db
    cur.execute(tableDecl)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alba/Fernando/SQL/Galvez_Sanchez_Fernando_Jose_SQL/Parseadores/DESEQ2_TE_only.py", line 130, in <module>
    db = open_clinvar_db(db_file)
  File "/home/alba/Fernando/SQL/Galvez_Sanchez_Fernando_Jose_SQL/Parseadores/DESEQ2_TE_only.py", line 49, in open_clinvar_db
    print("An error occurred: {}".format(e.args[0]), file=sys.stderr)
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Les dejo aquí debajo el código de python que uso para incorporar datos a SQL:

```
import sys, os

import sqlite3

# For compressed input files
#import gzip

import re
CLINVAR_TABLE_DEFS = [
"""
CREATE TABLE X (
    Clave INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Cromosoma VARCHAR(64),
    Inicio INTEGER,
    Final INTEGER,
    Subfamilia VARCHAR(64),
    Familia VARCHAR(64),
    Clase VARCHAR(64),
    Dup INTEGER,
    Strand VARCHAR(1),
    Log2FoldChange INTEGER,
    P.adj.value INTEGER
)
"""
]

def open_clinvar_db(db_file):
    """
        This method creates a SQLITE3 database with the needed
        tables to store clinvar data, or opens it if it already
        exists
    """
    
    db = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    
    cur = db.cursor()
    try:
        # Let's enable the foreign keys integrity checks
        cur.execute("PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS=ON")
        
        # And create the tables, in case they were not previously
        # created in a previous use
        for tableDecl in CLINVAR_TABLE_DEFS:
            cur.execute(tableDecl)
    except sqlite3.Error:
        print("An error occurred: {}".format(e.args[0]), file=sys.stderr)
    finally:
        cur.close()
    
    return db
    

def new_func(cur):
    cur.execute
    
def store_clinvar_file(db,clinvar_file):
    with open(clinvar_file,"rt",encoding="utf-8") as cf:
        headerMapping = None
        #known_genes = set()
        
        cur = db.cursor()
        
        with db:
            for line in cf:
                # First, let's remove the newline
                wline = line.rstrip("\n")
                
                # Now, detecting the header
                if (headerMapping is None) and (wline[0] == '#'):
                    wline = wline.lstrip("#")
                    columnNames = re.split(r"\t",wline)
                    
                    headerMapping = {}
                    # And we are saving the correspondence of column name and id
                    for columnId, columnName in enumerate(columnNames):
                        headerMapping[columnName] = columnId
##MODIFICACIÓN 2##
                else:
                    # We are reading the file contents  
                    columnValues = re.split(r" ",wline)
                    
                    # As these values can contain "nulls", which are
                    # designed as '-', substitute them for None
                    for iCol, vCol in enumerate(columnValues):
                        if len(vCol) == 0 or vCol =="na":
                            columnValues[iCol] = None
                    # And extracting what we really need
                    # Table variation
                    Cromosoma = columnValues[headerMapping["cromosoma"]]
                    Inicio = int(columnValues[headerMapping["inicio"]])
                    Final = int(columnValues[headerMapping["final"]])
                    Subfamilia = columnValues[headerMapping["subfamilia"]]
                    Familia = columnValues[headerMapping["familia"]]
                    Clase = columnValues[headerMapping["clase"]]
                    Dup = int(columnValues[headerMapping["dup"]])
                    Strand = columnValues[headerMapping["strand"]]
                    Log2FoldChange = int(columnValues[headerMapping["log2foldchange"]])
                    P.adj.value = int(columnValues[headerMapping["padjvalue"]])
                    
                    cur.execute("""
                        INSERT INTO DESEQ_TE_ONLY(
                            Cromosoma,
                            Inicio,
                            Final,
                            Subfamilia,
                            Familia,
                            Clase,
                            Dup,
                            Strand,
                            Log2FoldChange,
                            P.adj.value,
                            )
                        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                    """, (Cromosoma,Inicio,Final,Subfamilia,Familia,Clase, Dup, Strand, Log2FoldChange,P.adj.value))
        cur.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("Usage: {0} {{database_file}} {{compressed_clinvar_file}}".format(sys.argv[0]), file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

    # Only the first and second parameters are considered
    db_file = sys.argv[1]
    clinvar_file = sys.argv[2]

    # First, let's create or open the database
    db = open_clinvar_db(db_file)

    # Second
    store_clinvar_file(db,clinvar_file)

    db.close()
```

Los únicos cambios que hay son los contenidos de las tablas y la versión de python ya que este script se puso a punto en python 3.8 y actualmente se usa con python 3.9, aunque entiendo que es algo que no debería de dar problema.

Comment: El error puntual es que falta definir la variable `e` entiendo que es por esto `except sqlite3.Error` que debiera ser `except sqlite3.Error as e`

Comment: De paso, bienvenido Fernandogs97 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho, he superado ese error pero sigo teniendo la misma serie de errores. Gracias por el consejo, me veré el recorrido en este dia

Comment: El tema es que tu pregunta es sobre un error, que ya está solucionado, por lo cual ya no tiene sentido. Puedes 1) editar tu pregunta cambiar el título y plantear los otros errores que me dices que tienes 2) eliminar la pregunta y crear una nueva